# assigning the parameter to a new value inside the function, good or bad practice?

Tags: javascript, redux, parameters

May be a simple question but i really can't figure out if this would be good or bad in the term of practice.

I am using redux to manage state and i always do my logic in actions, which take the old state, perform some logic and message reducers:

**action**(demo)

```
const updateFilters = (filters) => {
  filters =  filters.map(...);
}
```

but my mind goes for creating a new variable instead:

```
const updateFilters = (filters) => {
  const newFilters = filters.map(...)
}
```

**My question is:**
Is assigning the parameter name to a new value(in the first code snippet) is **safe** and **not a bad practice**??

Comment: yes, it's safe because you're merely reassigning a local variable.

Comment: (Re)assingments are sometimes an indicator that your function does too much. Instead of (re)assign a variable you could also just return the value or call another function with that value as an argument.

Comment: What does this have to do with functional programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be differentiating from `is it safe?` and `is it a good practice?`

1. Is reassigning a local variable safe? Yes, it is.
2. Is reassigning a (local) variable a good practice? **Not necessarily**.

Reassigning variables is error prone and compromises readability of your program. There are a lot of style guide that explicitly forbid it because:

- Prevents you from accessing the original value assigned to that variable
- Creates confusion

---

My personal opinion is that you could simply treat every variable as not-to-be-reassigned, this would just make your program clearer and therefore reduce the risk of unintended behaviour.

---

> Assignment to variables declared as function parameters can be misleading and lead to confusing behavior, as modifying function parameters will also mutate the arguments object. Often, assignment to function parameters is unintended and indicative of a mistake or programmer error.

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign

---

also read:

- https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-shadow